# Laravel: Resource controllers and validation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Resource controllers in Laravel. What I want to do is a really simple workflow.
1) using the `create` function to show the form to insert data
2) using the `store` function to save the resource

I can't understand which is the right way to build a simple environment like that, using validation.

Here some questions: 
In the `create` function I show the form:

```
return View:make('form');
```

**1)** Where has to point the form's action? I suppose to the `store` function.

**2)** Where I have to perform validation? In my opinion if the form points to the `store` I can perform validation in this function. If validation fails I redirect to `Create`.

**3)** The "default" `create` function hasn't any parameter in input. How can I redirect to this function passing error messages?

What do you think about this workflow? How do you work with resource controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View::make` method only makes your view. In your view, you need to make your forms. You can use the `Form::open` or `Form::model` methods inside your view along with all the other `Form::` methods for inputs. Your controller should process the input and either your controller or model can save the input.

For #3, there isn't supposed to be any parameters for `create` as it's for a new record. `show`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy` all accept an ID parameter.

See: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: And for your answer about #3. Ok... so how can the create function be notified about errors in input fields?

Comment: Ah, gotchya. You'll need to specify the form's action and method. Example: `Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'PUT/DELETE/etc'))` - this will create the `_method` hidden input box that allows the framework to know what we're doing and ultimately what action to call. Also, inside of your `Form::open` you can also use `'action' => 'MyController@action'` instead of `url`.

Comment: For errors in validation, you simply use the validator: http://laravel.com/docs/validation - then you're able to pass the errors to your view `View::make('foo')->withErrors($validator)`